# How can I render a networkDynamic network using the MDSJ rendering engine in R?

Tags: r, sna, statnet

I would like to render a dynamic network in R using the fast MDSJ library. Unfortunately, however, all the vertices' coordinates seem to be `0,0` using this rendering engine, which is not the case when using one of the other layouts (`kamadakawai` or `Graphviz`. If you paste the code below, you should be able to reproduce the problem.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
library("pacman")
pacman::p_load(network, networkDynamic, ndtv)

#animation.mode = "MDSJ"
#animation.mode = "Graphviz"
animation.mode = "kamadakawai"
people <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
documents <- paste0("a",1:10)
edges <- data.frame(from   = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D"),
                    to     = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a1","a1"),
                    active = c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4))
net <- network.initialize(0, directed = TRUE, bipartite = length(people))

add.vertices.networkDynamic(net, 5, vertex.pid = people)
add.vertices.networkDynamic(net, 10, vertex.pid = documents)

net %v% "vertex.names" <- c(people, documents)
net %v% "vertex.col"   <- c(rep("blue", length(people)), rep("gray", length(documents)))
set.network.attribute(net,'vertex.pid','vertex.names')

add.edges.networkDynamic(net,
                         tail = get.vertex.id(net, edges[[1]]),
                         head = get.vertex.id(net, edges[[2]]),
                         edge.pid = paste0(edges[[1]], "->", edges[[2]]))
activate.edges(net, e =  1:7, at = edges[[3]])
reconcile.vertex.activity(net = net, mode = "encompass.edges", edge.active.default = FALSE)

slice.par <- list(start = 1, end = 4, interval = 1, aggregate.dur = 2, rule = "earliest")
compute.animation(net,
                  animation.mode = animation.mode,
                  slice.par = slice.par)
render.d3movie(net,
               slice.par = slice.par,
               displaylabels = TRUE,
               output.mode = "htmlWidget",
               vertex.col = 'vertex.col')
```

Using kamadakawai, one gets a dynamic view like this:

[image]

Using MDSJ, all slides look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code works on my system with MDSJ. Does it install correctly on yours? When it's first used, it has to download and install a Java application mdsj.jar.

Comment: Yes, upon first use, I was asked for permission to download and install MDSJ. This succeeded, and I now do see that MDSJ gets called during the process. For some reason, however, it does not work as expected as explained above. I have Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan and Java 8 Update 101 build 13 and RStudio Version 0.99.896. Did you activate MDSJ in the snippet above by uncommenting the #animation.mode = "MDSJ" and commenting out "kamadakawai"?

Comment: Yes, I did. How would I know, assuming that I had never used the software before, that it asks for a java download if I did not?

Also, I'm using an earlier version of the Mac OS that does not have the permissions issues of El Capitan, though if your other R packages are working, that should be fine. Does anything else that uses RJava work normally. I also don't use RStudio, though I can't see how that makes any difference.

Comment: The package rJava was not installed, but installing it did not change anything.

Comment: And what kind of error messages (if any) do you get?

I see:
`[1] "MDSJ starting stress: 3.2711604543709853"  "MDSJ ending stress: 4.0077515393037346E-4"
Calculating layout for network slice from time  2 to 4
[1] "MDSJ starting stress: 11.61592059726994" "MDSJ ending stress: 0.5122455877471873" 
Calculating layout for network slice from time  3 to 5
[1] "MDSJ starting stress: 12.664186182271857" "MDSJ ending stress: 1.306168183018367"   
Calculating layout for network slice from time  4 to 6
[1] "MDSJ starting stress: 1.8375857926346992" "MDSJ ending stress: 0.07398826173255649" 
`

Comment: `Calculating layout for network slice from time  1 to 3
[1] "coordinate array is missing entries for row 0 col 0 ?" "coordinate array is missing entries for row 0 col 1 ?"
[3] "coordinate array is missing entries for row 1 col 0 ?" "coordinate array is missing entries for row 1 col 1 ?"
[5] "coordinate array is missing entries for row 2 col 0 ?" "coordinate array is missing entries for row 2 col 1 ?"
[7] "MDSJ starting stress: 6.0"                             "MDSJ ending stress: 6.0" `